# Meaning of match pattern in web extension manifest.json file

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pattern-matching, manifest.json

What does this *match pattern* declaration in manifest.json file imply ?
I read from the following URL and can't find any results.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

[image]

Comment: It allows accessing/intercepting/modifying data on the tabs/requests with the matching URLs e.g. fetch/XHR, webRequest, webNavigation listeners, injection of content scripts, taking screenshots, and so on.

Comment: So does it has similar purpose to "content_scripts": [{"matches": [<patern>]}] ?

Comment: Content scripts declare a script that automatically runs in a tab/frame with that URL whereas the `permissions` key allows to handle the matching URLs in the extension's own pages like the popup script, background script, etc.